# Maven local artifactory file edit

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I have uploaded some of the jars to the my local artifactory...

For a example....
Repository Browser
+--org
 |-jboos
 |-json
  |json-java
   |-maven-metadata.xml

This xml file Dependency Declaration shown as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>json-java</version>
    <type>xml</type>
</dependency>
```

I need to change this xml file for a reason. Is there anyway to do this artifactory UI itself. (Without login to the locale artifactory server )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not upload maven-metadata files. They are generated by Artifactory for you. 
Second, since Artifactory usually manages uneditable binary files, there is no edit functionality in Artifactory.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: is it possible to manually edit these files by logging to the application server

Comment: No. Artifactory doesn't store the files in plain filesystem.

Comment: If i need to change the pom.xml licence information of a jar , this https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/License+Control add-one should work , right ... ?

Comment: No. This doesn't change a pom file. Actually, as I mentioned before, nothing in Arifactory does.